# WSO2 null response

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am trying to use WSO2 [StoreAPI](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Store+APIs) in my code for performing validations from WSO2.Here is a snippet

```
def wso2Subscription(){
        println "Inside Subscription"
        def serverName = grailsApplication.config.grails.wsoconfig.serverName.toString()
        println serverName
        withHttp(uri: serverName) {
            def resp = post(path : '/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag', query : [action:'addAPISubscription',name:'NewAPI',version:'1.0.0',provider:'admin',tier:'Unlimited',applicationName:'DefaultApplication'])
            println  "Subscription Response from WS02 ="+resp
            resp.each { h -> println " ${h.key} : ${h.value}" }
        }
    }
```

This value of resp is null everytime. What is missing here? I already login and perform this operation. Also, the user is not subscribed to this API previously. "Inside Subscription" is displayed and hence, the function is getting called. However, the response is null always. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was session management which was not being possible here. A very good reference is this link on solving this. It worked for me!
      http://refaktor.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-keep-session-in-httpbuilder-with.html

Answer (score 1):

You should send below information as body, not as query string.

```
action:'addAPISubscription',name:'NewAPI',version:'1.0.0',provider:'admin',tier:'Unlimited',applicationName:'DefaultApplication'
```

It's better you send the request from [cURL](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Store+APIs#StoreAPIs-AddaSubscription) and see the response.

Comment: I am able to get the response from cURL only after I login first. Here , I am logging in, but I feel somehow it is unable to hit the Url. Probably cURL has the option of posting to cookies, and none exist here. So any other way?